# speeding up records fetch time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, performance-testing

I have a SQL sentence which takes around 44 Sec to fetch the data. how can I reduce the time ?

this is the sql

```
Select AVNR,replace(to_char((CAST(DBTM as timestamp)),'hh24:mi'),'00:00','24:00') as ptime,
        Wert
From e_mw_60min_me
Where to_char((CAST ( DBTM as TIMESTAMP)), 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '13-03-1396'  and
      AVNR In (1141,1142,1144,10335,10336,12016,1146,1147,1149,1129,1130,1132,1134,1135,1137,5895,5896,5900,8906,8907,8909,8901,8902,8904,8940,8941,8943,8951,8952,8954,8972,8973,8975,8830,8831,8833,8835,8836,8838,1113,1982,1984,2314,2315,2317,3272,3273,3275,3267,3268,3270,3262,3263,3265,10231,10136,9066,8779,8780,8782,8774,8775,8777,8320,8321,8323,7696,7697,7699,10486,10487,10489,3329,3330,12018,3322,3328,10132,3320,3321,12017,3222,3223,3225,686,687,689,691,692,694,696,697,699,1,2,4,10527,10528,10529,4911,4912,4914,4917,4918,4920,5162,5163,5166,5157,5158,5160,5168,5169,5171,5449,5450,5452,10116,10117,10119,10120,10121,10123,2271,2272,2279,2266,2267,2269,2259,2260,2262,1292,1293,1295,5380,5381,5383,5374,5375,5377,10545,10546,10547,3281,10126,12031,3244,3245,12030,10983,10984,12033,10987,10989,12032,11073,11074,1125,11079,11080,3333,105,106,108,100,101,103,93,94,96,29,30,32,95,102,1197,124,123,126,12085,12086,12087,2520,2521,2523,2525,2526,2528,2515,2516,2518,2510,2511,2513,5444,5445,5447,2201,2202,12025,3336,3337,3339,3002,3003,12029,1643,1644,1646,1609,1610,1612,1596,1597,1599,9717,9718,9720,9722,9723,9725,2146,2147,2149,2141,2142,2144,2136,2137,2139,2131,2132,2134,2121,2122,2124,2126,2127,2129,2635,2636,2638,2641,2642,2644,7499,7500,7502,4610,4611,4613,4605,4606,4608,4600,4601,4603,9074,9075,9077,9079,9080,9082,9235,9236,9238,9240,9241,9243,9245,9246,9248,8468,8469,8471,5785,5786,5788,5790,5791,5793,5691,5692,5694,5685,5686,5688,8455,8456,8458,11312,11313,4588,7654,7655,7657,9376,9377,9379,9371,9372,9374,9382,9383,9385,5918,5919,5922,5934,5935,5938,5912,5913,5916,10963,7860,10964,135,136,138,10658,10659,10664,10660,10661,10662,5173,5458,5460);

 //these AVNRs are completley Dynamic
```

the Table is like :

1. AVNR (Like ID Number)
2. DBTM( reocrds every time for every points)
3. Wert (the value)

I want to know any other sql command which makes it faster to fetch

Comment: Why are you casting DBTM? What data type is it? And what indexes do you have on the table? When looking at query optimisation you really need to include table and index information and your current query's execution plan.

Comment: I don't have any access to change the database, but DBTM is DATE. but what it shows is Date + time, So I need date and time seperately

Comment: How much data do you have? How many records in total? How many per date element of DBTM? What indexes have you built on the table? How much time do you wan to shave off that 44 secs?

Answer (score 2):

If DBTM is a date you don't need to cast it to a timestamp; and if there is an index on that then you should not convert it to a string to compare with another string - leave it as a date and convert the fixed value to a date too, and compare with a range that covers the entire day:

```
select AVNR,
  replace(to_char(DBTM,'hh24:mi'),'00:00','24:00') as ptime,
  Wert
from e_mw_60min_me
where DBTM >= date '1396-03-13'
and DBTM < date '1396-03-14'
and AVNR In (1141, ...);
```

I've used date literals but you can use `to_date()` if you are starting from a variable string:

```
where DBTM >= to_date('13-03-1396', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
and DBTM < to_date('13-03-1396', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1
and AVNR In (1141, ...);
```

You should also consider creating a collection for all the AVNR values you are looking for and using `member of` instead if `IN`, or explode the collection and join to it. It depends where those values are coming from though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an index:

```
create index idx_e_mw_60min_me_2 on (to_char((CAST ( DBTM as TIMESTAMP)), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), AVNR)
```

This exactly matches the `where` clause so it should speed up the query.

Comment: I have a index on AVNR and DBTM, because the combination is unique

Comment: @nnmmss . . . This is a single, composite index.

Comment: so , by that you mean...?

Comment: @nnmmss . . . Exactly the index specified in the answer.

Comment: If you are creating a separate index just to service this query, you might as well throw `wert` in there at the end and avoid the table access altogether.